# Load external PHP file within a PHP only once

Tags: php

I would like to call an external PHP file whenever a PHP page loads. This external PHP file should be loaded only once, even if the user refreshes the page. How can I go about it? Can I do an interval of how long the user has to wait before this external PHP file is called?

Answer (score 2):

You can use require_once and session.

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['executed'])) {
   require_once('your_file.php');
   $_SESSION['executed'] = true;
}
```

Comment: Is using a session absolutely necessary here? It seems like it would be simpler to just use a plain cookie.

Comment: Also is `require_once()` necessary? The `_once` functionality only applies to the request. Subsequent requests will have a new `_once` already loaded file list.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder actually it shouldn't matter if it's `_once` or not, but don't hurt. Yes the code can use plain cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in a file or better in a database last time you exectued this external file. So each time this file is called you compare the last time it was called and exit if it's not too long